# Why I need add use_legacy_build_api: true when use gym build project?

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane

Why I need add use_legacy_build_api: true when use gym build project?

I used Xcode 7.3 and gym 1.6.2,

I build a new Projct(OC or swift is same),

Below is error output:

```
2016-04-22 18:45:46.071 xcodebuild[135:10371572] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID F41BD31E-2683-44B8-AE7F-5F09E919790E for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/BBUFullIssueNavigator.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2016-04-22 18:45:46.246 xcodebuild[135:10371572] ### Failed to load Addressbook class CNContactNameFormatter
2016-04-22 18:45:46.300 xcodebuild[135:10371572] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/4w/fpkx9n7s3gnbcxfym8mqr18m0000gn/T/GymDemo_2016-04-22_18-45-46.299.xcdistributionlogs'.
2016-04-22 18:45:46.585 xcodebuild[135:10371572] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionSigningAssetsStep: 0x7ff847a3e450>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
error: exportArchive: The operation couldn’t be completed. (IDEDistributionErrorDomain error 1.)

Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"

** EXPORT FAILED **
[18:45:46]: Exit status: 70

[!] Error packaging up the application
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't known why there is error, but I just use fastlane init and I change the fastlane，everythings is ok. This is my fastfile：

```
desc "Deploy a new version to the App Store"
  lane :appstore do
    # match(type: "appstore")
    # snapshot
    #sigh
    gym(
      scheme: "myscheme_iOS",
      export_method:"app-store",
      output_directory:"./fastlane",
      output_name:"myipa_20160607030055",
      codesigning_identity:"iPhone Distribution: Jack Zhou (9R46C82WH7)"
    ) # Build your app - more options available
    #deliver(force: true)
    # frameit
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

The flag `use_legacy_build_api` should be used only if you're running with Xcode 6 or before.

As explained by [Felix Krause](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445598/krausefx) itself on [Github](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/6321):

> **What is use_legacy_build_api**?
>   It's using the Xcode 6 build API, which is not officially supported any more.

What happened was that between Xcode 6 and 7 several changes were made to the build/packaging process, so in order to adapt to the new process and still be able to work with the old one fastlane introduced this new flag that basically inform which command to use.

**Xcode 7**

Since you're using the Xcode 7 you need to specify how you want to export your application, that is the same choice you need to make when you're using Xcode itself:
[image: Exporting archive using Xcode]

You can also read more about export methods on the Apple documentation [Exporting Your App](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html)

**Gym**

So as explained above using Fastlane you should specify the `export_method` field accordingly:

`gym(export_method:"app-store|ad-hoc|package|enterprise|development|developer-id")`

You can read more about Gym and its parameters on the [fastlane actions documentation](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/#gym)

- **use_legacy_build_api**: [DEPRECATED!] Don't use this option any more, as it's deprecated by Apple - Don't use this option any more, as it's deprecated by Apple
- **export_method**: Method used to export the archive. Valid values are: app-store, ad-hoc, package, enterprise, development, developer-id